# How to remove application context from URL in apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, url, tomcat, contextpath

I have a war test.war. I deployed it in webapps folder.

Now I can access the web application by URL www.domain.com/test/login

In order to remove the war name, I renamed the war to ROOT.war

So Now I am able to access the web application by URL www.domain.com/login

Can someone please guide me How to access the web application by URL www.domain.com

P.S I cannot modify the contents of my WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Put a HTTP server in front of your application server. That will allow you to create and redirect virtual hosts into specific URLs inside your application server. It's called a reverse proxy.

E.g.

```
www.domain.com -> localhost:8080/mylogin
subdomain.domain.com -> localhost:8080/otherapp/frontpage
```

Comment: where to write the above two lines. in my case it will www.domain.com -> localhost/login

Comment: It's not that simple, and it depends on the HTTP server you're using. But it's the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tomcat 7+, you can use an empty URI pattern in your web.xml to map an empty request to the context root.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
     ...
</servlet>

 ...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping> It is not wokring !!

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using? Also, have you mapped the name "login" to an actual servlet in your web.xml?  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8 has a URL rewrite mechanism.similar to
Apache's mod_rewrite.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html